# Fragment slide animation for every screen size?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

The navigation in my app is fragment based, and i would like to add slide-in and slide-out animations.

I tried like this:

An example of my animation xmls in animator folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
  <objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="x" 
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-1000" 
    android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

And i use fragmentTransaction like this:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.from_right, R.animator.to_left, R.animator.from_left, R.animator.to_right);
```

Well it is nice and working but i really liked the old version of animations where i could define percentage animation "distance", but my app is android 4.0+ so i cannot use the old anim method.

In this way multiple screen sizes are not supported.

Could someone suggest me a way to make dynamic animations for every screen size?

Comment: You can make the animation dynamically in code, not using XML. Then you can set the values to and from based on the pixel width of the screen which you can get first.

Comment: And how could i add animation from code to fragmentTransaction's setCustomAnimations function? It's arguments are integers referencing for xml files... or m i wrong?

Comment: Why can't you use a view animation xml? You can use percentages there.